# Назначение интерфейсов

Tags: golang

Пытаюсь понять, назначение интерфейсов. Написал такой пример:

```
package main

type Talker interface {
    Talk()
}

type Person1 struct {
    text string
}
type Person2 struct {
    text string
}

func (n *Person1) Talk() {
    println("person1 says", n.text)
}

func (n *Person2) Talk() {
    println("person2 says", n.text)
}

func Converse(l Talker) {
    l.Talk()
}

func main() {
    Converse(&Person1{"hello"})
    Converse(&Person2{"hi"})
}
```

И написав его, могу сформулировать назначение интерфеса так:

Если объект реализует не все методы интерфеса или реализует хотя бы один из методов не с той сигнатурой, что указана в интерфесе, то обьект не сможет иметь доступ к универсальным функциям обьектов этого интерфейса(в моем примере такая функция Converse(l Talker)).

Неужели, назначение интерфесов только в, своего рода, инкапсуляции обьекта и его данных?
Выглядит так, как будто это защита от программиста, который не понимает, что он делает, и какими методами и функциями нужно обрабатывать объекты и данные, а интерфес, как бы, уточняет у него, "ты точно уверен, что этот объект должен обрабатываться именно этой функцией?"
Раньше я не рассмтаривал интерфесы в этом ключе, так как всегда их преподносят как средство универсализации чего то и я не могу их понять, пока ищу эту универсализацию, потому что не наблюдаю универсализацию(методы Talk, все равно, нужно писать разные для каждого обьекта)

Дополняю по ответам:

```
    package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

type MoveSaveReader interface {
    Copy()
    Save()
    Read()
}

type OBJ struct {
    data, filename, newpath string
}

type NewObj struct {
    data, path string
}

func (o *NewObj) Copy() {
}

func (o *NewObj) Save() {
    err := os.WriteFile(o.path, []byte(o.data), 6060)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Saved")
}

func (o *NewObj) Read() {
    d, err := os.ReadFile(o.path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    o.data = string(d)
}

func (o *OBJ) Copy() {
    o.Read()
    o.filename = o.newpath
    o.Save()
}

func (o *OBJ) Save() {
    err := os.WriteFile(o.filename, []byte(o.data), 6060)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Saved")
}

func (o *OBJ) Read() {
    d, err := os.ReadFile(o.filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    o.data = string(d)
}

func CopyFile(m MoveSaveReader) {
    m.Copy()
}

func WriteNewFile(m MoveSaveReader) {
    m.Save()
}

func ReadFile(m MoveSaveReader) {
    m.Read()
}

func main() {
    obj := &OBJ{"sometext", "path", "newpath"}
    WriteNewFile(obj)
    ReadFile(obj)
    CopyFile(obj)
    newObj := &NewObj{"newtext", "newSomePAth"}
    WriteNewFile(newObj)
    ReadFile(newObj)
}
```

Объекты , у которых нет хотя бы одно из методов `MoveSaveReader`-а, а именно: `Copy()`, `Save()`, `Read()` или методы есть но хотя бы один неправильно сигнатуры, то такой объект защищен от ошибочного помещения в функции `CopyFile(m MoveSaveReader)`, `ReadFile(m MoveSaveReader)`, `WriteFile(m MoveSaveReader)`. Т.е с помощью интерфесов я больше не универсализирую обработку данных  а защищаю?

Comment: Универсализация не в том, что методод Talk надо надо писать у каждого объекта, а в том, что функция Converse может работать с любым объектом которые реализует интерфейс Talker. Хоть с человеком, хоть с попугаем, хоть с ChatGPT.

Comment: @Quester универсальность и duck typing в первую очередь, безопасность во вторую. Плюс я не написал, что интерфейсы упрощают тестирование. Вместо конкретной структуры можно подсунуть заглушку (mock), реализующую методы. Это гораздо легче, чем генерировать заглушку для конкретной структуры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если коротко, то основное назначение интерфейсов - реализация парадигмы *type safe duck typing*.

Если более развёрнуто.

Не знаю, как вы, а я познакомился с интерфейсами в языке Java. Там интерфейс - это такой тип, у которого есть только сигнатуры методов, нет ни данных, ни тел методов. Если какой-то класс реализует интерфейс, то в нём есть все методы интерфейса. Например интерфейс [`Closable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), в котором всего один метод `void close()`. В стандартной библиотеке Java несколько десятков классов, реализующих интерфейс `Closable`, и в каждом, что характерно, есть метод `close`.

В чём различие между интерфейсами java и go, и причём тут **duck typing**.

В Java связь между интерфейсом и типом *слева направо*: если тип реализует интерфейс, значит, в типе есть все методы интерфейса. В go направление обратное. Если в типе реализованы все методы интерфейса, то тип реализует интерфейс.

Разница, на самом деле, огромная. В Java тип реализует только те интерфейсы, которые перечислили разработчики класса. Если они что-то не упомянули, то хоть ты тресни, но привести тип к нужному интерфейсу не получится.

Пример. Восхотелось мне задать интерфейс

```java
interface Writable {
    void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException;
}
```

В библиотеке `java.io` есть класс [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) в котором, среди прочего, есть метод [`Writer.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-char:A-int-int-) с как раз подходящей сигнатурой. Означает ли это, что объекты класса `java.io.Writer` заодно являются объектами типа `Writable`? Нет, не означает, так как создатели класса `Writer` не знали о существовании моего интерфейса `Writable`, не указали его в разделе `implements`, и, тем самым, не включили в список типов объектов `Writer`.

В Go ситуация обратная. При создании типа никто не перечисляет интерфейсы, которые тип реализует. При проверке приводимости объекта к интерфейсу компилятор проверяет, чтобы у типа были все необходимые методы. Если методы есть, значит тип реализует интерфейс. Так, все типы, имеющие метод `func (T) Write([]byte)(int,error)` реализуют интерфейс [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) просто потому, что реализуют небходимый метод. Даже если сами не знают об этом.

*Выглядит как утка, ходит как утка, крякает как утка - значит, утка.*

Теперь про **type safety**.

Duck typing встречается сплошь и рядом в интерпретируемых языках. Python, Javascript, Ruby, Lisp, ... несть им числа. В любом из этих языков вы можете написать что-то вроде `stream.write(buf)` (в случае Лиспа это будет `(write stream buf)`), и молиться про себя, чтобы у `stream` таки нашелся метод `write`, который умеет обрабатывать объекты типа `buf`. Если ваша молитва услышана, то всё хорошо, программа работает. Но если нужного метода нет, то вы узнаете об этом только во время выполнения программы. Особенно обидно, если этот `write` вызывается в самом конце длииииинного вычисления, и все результаты бессмысленно теряются из-за того, что `stream` *не той системы*.

В go компилятор проверяет, что в объекте есть необходимые методы: совпадают имена, типы параметров, типы возвращаемых значений. Если хоть что-то не совпало, то вы об этом узнаете ещё на этапе компиляции. Программа просто не соберётся.

Так, если вы напишете что-то вроде `func save_results(data Data, sink io.Writable) { ...; _, err := sink.Write(data.Bytes()); ... }` то можете быть железно уверены, что в объекте `sink` есть метод с именем `Write`, и этот метод

- принимает единственный параметр типа `[]byte`,
- возвращает два значения,
- и тип второго значения `error`.

Если этот код сломается во время выполнения, то не по причине отсутствия нужного метода.

Comment: получается я все же правильно понял интерфейсы. нельзя бездумно пихать обьекты в универсальную функцию. Объекту недостаточно быть обьектом, а он должен еще и соответствовать контракту в интерфейсе. То есть интерфейсы, по сути, просто дисциплинируют программиста и это история не про универсализацию?то что можно принять за универсализацию, на самом деле ограничение во избежание ошибок.

Comment: Можно привети функции в качестве аналогии: я не могу написать функцию с 2мя принимаемыми параметрами, а вызывать с одним. В такой аналогии,  интерфейс это функция, а методы интерфейса это принимаемые параметры.

Comment: @Quester универсализация, конечно, же, есть. Если не использовать интерфейсы, то под каждую задачу нужно писать отдельную функцию - например, чтение файла, копирования содержимого буфера, сохранения тела HTTP-ответа. А с интерфейсами достаточно универсальной функции [`io.Copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy), которая читает из `Reader` и пишет в `Writer`. Но и type safety важна - интерфейсы гарантируют, что у аргументов универсальной функции будут необходимые методы

Comment: @Quester аналогия, честно признаюсь, довольно тумманная для меня, но, наверное, верная. Скажем, есть интерфейс [`io.ReadWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadWriter), в котором два метода - `Read` и `Write`. Если в объекте только один метод, то увы, он никак не может быть объектом интерфейса.

Comment: дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: является ли дополнение хоть сколько нибудь правильным подходом?